# Creating custom automatic compile error/warning message in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I've been creating a library and I thought of adding a feature where if a user tries to do something funny, XCode will show an error/warning message that pops up in red/yellow boxes respectively, automatically. I've been trying to find resources related to this, but I've been unsuccessful. To be more clear, I've been trying to create custom messages in situations like these images below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can look to [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint). Its looks like your library.